# Adding a zero columns to a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a strange problem which i am not able to figure out. I have a dataframe subset that looks like this

[image]

in the dataframe, I add "zero" columns using the following code:

```
subset['IRNotional]=pd.DataFrame(numpy.zeros(shape=(len(subset),1)))
subset['IPNotional]=pd.DataFrame(numpy.zeros(shape=(len(subset),1)))
```

and i get a result similar to this

[image]

Now when i do similar things to another dataframe i get zeros columns with a mix NaN and zeros rows as shown below. This is really strange.

```
subset['IRNotional]=pd.DataFrame(numpy.zeros(shape=(len(subset),1)))
    subset['IPNotional]=pd.DataFrame(numpy.zeros(shape=(len(subset),1)))
```

[image]

I dont understand why sometimes i get zeros the other i get either NaNs or a mix of NaNs and zeros. Please help if you can

Thanks

Comment: Do `subset['IRNotional'] = 0` to assign a column of `0`s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you need [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with dictionary for set new columns names:

```
subset = subset.assign(**dict.fromkeys(['IRNotional','IPNotional'], 0))
#you can define each column separately
#subset = subset.assign(**{'IRNotional': 0, 'IPNotional': 1})
```

Or simplier:

```
subset['IRNotional'] = 0
subset['IPNotional'] = 0
```

> Now when i do similar things to another dataframe i get zeros columns with a mix NaN and zeros rows as shown below. This is really strange.

I think problem is different index values, so is necessary create same indices, else for not matched indices get `NaN`s:

```
subset['IPNotional']=pd.DataFrame(numpy.zeros(shape=(len(subset),1)), index=subset.index)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jezrael. It was confusing the hell out of me. Just like you said i ll keep it simple and stick to the simplier version you suggested

Comment: @SBad - yes, I think I find problem, added to answer. You can test with your data